# How can i implement this select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm a new to SQL Server, and have to import this data into a table:

[image]

I want to show me this data:

```
942,4600
952,4000
```

For that purpose I wrote this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(SQ.[price])
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         [sycle] as TRACK, [price] 
     FROM 
         [ClubEatc].[dbo].[testTABLE]) SQ
```

That query sums all `sycle` prices, but I want sum per `sycle`. How can I implement this? Thanks.

Comment: **Implement** - not "implant" ...

Comment: @marc_s excuse me my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **Group by SQ.sycle**:

It will set group of each unique sycle and do some of it's price.

```
SELECT 
   SQ.sycle,
   SUM(SQ.[price]) AS Price
FROM TableName SQ
Group By SQ.sycle
```